# Return a value inside a function after getting value from firebase storage closure Swift

Tags: swift, firebase

I have a function which downloads data from firebase:

```
func downloadData(path: String) -> Data? {
    let data: Data?

    let storage = Storage.storage()
    storage.reference(forURL: path).getData(maxSize: 1024 * 1024) { (result, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print("\(error)")
    } else {
        data = result
        print("finished")
    }

    return data // <-- this is called before closue ends
}
```

but it is not returning the value from storage closure.
I tried using a dispatch group

```
 func downloadData(path: String) -> Data? {
     ...
     let group = DispatchGroup()
     group.enter()
     storage.reference(forURL: path).getData(maxSize: 1024 * 1024) { (result, error) in 
         ...
         ...
         group.leave()
     }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        return data // <-- build time error! the function doesn't return a value
    }
}
```

so I tried a different approach: instead of group.notify() I used:

```
group.wait()
```

but it didn't work also. the whole app was frozen and nothing happened

and I tried another one:

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)


storage.reference(forURL: path).getData(maxSize: 1024 * 1024) { (result, error) in 
    ...
    ...
    semaphore.signal()
}

semaphore.wait()

return data // <-- nothing happens... it is not being executed
```

Any ideas on how to figure this out?

***UPDATE***

I tried using the completion option but it still didn't wait until it is downloded.

this is my outerFunction:

```
    var soundData: Data?
    var imageData: Data?
    downloadData(path: soundPath) { sound in 
        soundData = sound

        downloadData(path: imageData) { image in
             imageData = image
        }

    }

    doMoreStuff() // <-- called before completeion blocks executed
```

Comment: could you please check scope of the `downloadData(path:)`? then please update your question with correct `{`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use completion block for data instead of returning the data, here's how:

```swift
func downloadData(path: String, completion: @escaping ((Data?) -> Void)?) {
    ...
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    var data: Data?
    storage.reference(forURL: path).getData(maxSize: 1024 * 1024) { (result, error) in
        ...
            ...
                data = dataReceived
                group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion?(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: as I understand you've copied the code block in my answer, please change `completion` to `data` in `notify` block or argument level

Comment: I tried this approach, it didn't work as I planned
I updated the post

Comment: @emrcftci I copied from the question I usually use completion as parameter name bt when I modified the function parameter it turned out different.

Answer (score 1):

Use completion instead of returning ->

```swift
func downloadData(path: String, _ completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
    let data: Data?

    let storage = Storage.storage()
    storage.reference(forURL: path).getData(maxSize: 1024 * 1024) { (result, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("\(error)")
        } else {
            data = result
            print("finished")
        }
        completion(data)
    }
}
```

---

Usage of the `downloadData(path:,_)`

```swift
downloadData(path: "") { data in
    // Your data is in here 
    print("Data is:", data)
}
```

Comment: Is your updated question working?? You're passing `imageData` to `downloadData(path:)` function which has an argument `path: String` but `imageData` is `Data`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that without some kind of completion closure, because you'd be blocking the thread which calls the function, probably the UI thread.

Another alternative would be to use Apple's new Combine framework and return a Future

```
import Combine

func downloadData(path: String) -> Future<Data, Error> {
    return Future<Data, Error> { promise in
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        storage.reference(forURL: path).getData(maxSize: 1024 * 1024) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                promise(.failure(error))
            } else {
                promise(.success(result))
            }

        }
    }
}

var bag = Set<AnyCancellable>()

downloadData(path: "test")
    .subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { (res) in
        <#code#>
    }) { (data) in
        <#code#>
    }
.store(in: &bag)
```